# Windows Azure and Saving Settings

Tags: c#, azure, static, settings, cloud

I'd really appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to build an Azure-based website.  I'm already using Blob storage to store a large number of photographs.  What is the best way to store settings relating to the global configuration of the site?

For example, through the Administration interface some settings need to be able to be changed, such as 'FooterCopyrightText' or 'Countries' (with a list of area codes, etc.).  I don't want to build these in to Web.Config, or include it as a data file in App_Data.

If this was a local desktop application I could simply have it deserialize an XML file and store it in memory as a static variable, but this approach doesn't work for a scalable application on Azure.

My thought is to do something like store it in Azure Blob storage, and cache the settings.

Is this the right approach?

Thank you for any ideas or pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue on my recent project where we needed to store the HTML associated with various emails that we send out.  We ended up storing the text in Azure Table Storage which provides a cheap and fast way to store information like this that is globally accessible across several roles and websites.

Here is a [walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2008/10/28/walkthrough-simple-table-storage.aspx) to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Azure SQL](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/data-management/) to store the configuration data. It'd give you relational data (area codes tied to specific countries for example), and you wouldn't incur any costs for queries, which if you need to retrieve this configuration for every page load, might be a cost savings. Or Robert's approach is equally as good. It probably depends on the type of data and your access patterns for what's best.

With [Entity Framework and code-first migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj554735) it's relatively easy to create your configuration models, and then migrate as your needs change.

Comment: Thanks also for your suggestion, I plan to move a portion of the settings to SQL tables and then use Azure Table Storage for the rest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file.  Pretty much the same as a web.config or app.config but you have the ability to change the values on the fly via the Azure management console.  Of course, you have to use RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue instead of the normal ConfigurationManager class.

UPDATE:  This link is a little old but still looks like it covers what you'd need to know to use ServiceConfiguration.cscfg file http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63977/Windows-Azure-Development-Deep-Dive-Working-With-C